# how to create month->day upload path directories when processing upload submit

Tags: php, directory

what is the simple way to create folders and sub-folders as upload path?
based on witch day it is
example:

```
-files
 -2012 //year
   -01 //month
     +01 //day
     +02
     +03
     .
     .
     .
     +29
     +30
   +02 //month
   +03
   +04
   +05
   +06
   +07
 +2013
 .
 .
 .
```

is there any class or function to do this making directories?

Comment: What have you tried? Basically you need [`date()`](http://php.net/date) and [`mdkir()`](http://php.net/mkdir).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mkdir()`. It has an option to create folders recursively.

Then just build a path using your desired date,  and be sure to add `true` to the function.

Meaning something like :

```
mkdir("/2012/5/25", 0755, true);
```

To build your date path you need to use the PHP method `date()`, for further reading and examples read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Answer (score 3):

```
$base_dir = '/path/to/your/dir';
$new_dir = $base_dir.date('/Y/m/d/');
if(!file_exists($new_dir) AND is_writable($base_dir)) {
    mkdir($new_dir, 0755, true)
}
```

Comment: missing paranthesis : if(!file_exists($new_dir) AND is_writable($base_dir)`)`

Comment: you still missing semicolon              mkdir($new_dir, 0755, true);